# Include local photos in a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, camera, local-storage

I am working on a web app that I will use as a teaching aid in field biology.  This is aiming to be cross platform, and is being built using javascript/Jquery/Jquery mobile.  The app shows descriptions and photos of plants and animals students may see and allows students to save their own notes using local storage.  It is essential that this works offline, as students may be working in isolated locations, and currently I am using appcache to achieve this.

I would like to add in functionality that allows students to take photos of organisms and then add their own pictures to the description pages (i.e. add in local files to the web pages dynamically).  I have managed to use the Camera API to take photos directly from the browser and then display them within the page.  However I have not been able to work out how to call photos back at a later time.  I have found some references that suggest this is not possible, others suggesting encoding photos to the local storage (though I think our needs would far exceed the capacity for local storage).

Is there any way this can be achieved?  I apologise if the answer is obvious, I am a novice, trying to learn as I go along!

Comment: If the requirement is that the photos are being transferred between devices, you end up using a database and optionally an external server to save the photos.

Comment: Using some sort of server would be the straightforward way, mobile phones these days have AMP capacities

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to encode them and store them as text (base64 encoding is almost certainly the easiest), local storage would likely fill up pretty quickly but its not your only offline storage facility. All modern browsers support IndexedDB, and whilst there are some questions around capacity, largely you are only limited by the size of the hard drive.

I don't know if [this gist](https://github.com/jonnysmith1981/getIndexedDbSize/blob/master/getIndexedDbSize.js) still works but it looks like it should give you a ballpark of the storage capacity. [This article](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/04/17/indexeddb-and-limits) suggests that Chrome and Firefox are plenty large enough (IE didn't have an implementation at that time and Safari's was broken in many respects).

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.  I had not come across IndexDB before, but from the link, it looks like it could solve the problem.  It may also be better than local storage for other functions.  I will give it a go and report back.